# MVC 3 - Custom Registration with User Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, customization, registration

I have two types of users Client and Vendor for my MVC 3 application. **How can I customize the existing register.cshtml to offer an anonymous user the following options:**

- 1. To register as either a client or vendor
- 2. Offer custom registration options based on their choice

This has been quite a challenge thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can assign the `User` to `Role` then return functionality based on the role they choose.

Hope this helps.

In the controller you could have something like:

```
 public ActionResult Register(string role)
 {
     Roles.AddUserToRole(User, "role");

     if (User.IsInRole("Client"))
         return View("ClientRegistration");

     if ( User.IsInRole("Vendor"))
         return View("VendorRegistration");
 }
```

Comment: Can this code be used with either a dropdown list or a checkbox list?

Comment: You would need to use @Html.DropDownFor() in the view code. You will need to pass the data for the dropdown in a custom model. The data can just be a string that is passed to the view, Then post the choice to the action method that will execute the code above.

Comment: Hmmm. A bit confusing but you have put me in the right direction. I am wondering, is this a good page that I can look at for integrating roles into the registration process in an MVC 3 application? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx

Comment: Yes but you should really look at the MVC design pattern if you are unfamiliar with it. There are some good tutorials on www.asp.net/mvc. good luck.

Comment: Well I still can't figure it out but I checked the green box cause you took the time. Thanks mate!